# How do I install sharp on my AWS Lambda via the CDK with a custom install command?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, sharp

I have an error message asking me to install a specific version of `sharp` for my AWS lambda function: `npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp`.

Whilst I can do this locally, I believe the CDK just runs `npm i sharp`, which causes issues.

**Current CDK definition:**

```
this.sharpUser = new NodejsFunction(this, `sharpUser-${context.environment}`, {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
  handler: "handler",
  entry: join(__dirname, "./sharpUser.ts"),
  bundling: {
    nodeModules: ["sharp", "@aws-sdk/client-s3"],
    externalModules: ["aws-sdk"],
  },
});
```

**Error:**

```
  Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module
  
  Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'
  Require stack:
  - /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js
  - /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
  - /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
  - /var/task/index.js
  - /var/runtime/index.mjs
  
  Possible solutions:
  - Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"
  - Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"
  - Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
```

Answer (score 4):

this is how i got it working:

my cdk config for my nodejs function as follow:

```
 bundling: {
      nodeModules: ["sharp"],
      forceDockerBundling: true, // force docker bundling for sharp
 },
memorySize: 2048,
timeout: Duration.minutes(2)
```

then i went into my src folder , where the lambda code is stored.   Initialized a new project using npm:

```
npm init -y
npm install sharp
```

then import sharp lib as normal and use it:

```
import sharp from "sharp";
```

if using typescript you may need set this ts config file     `"esModuleInterop": true`

not the cleanest solution, but it worked for me :)

if not  u can look up `image-resizer-service` by AWS and use that.

Comment: thank you, the `bundling` args with `forceDockerBundling` fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Would that mean I need docker on my windows PC?

Comment: @Luke yup docker needs be installed on your PC

Answer (score 0):

Just use AWS lambda layer https://github.com/pH200/sharp-layer

Trust me this is the only way and best way to use sharp in AWS lambda